# Django autosetting user foriegnkey field to submitting user on form

Tags: django

What I'm trying to do is to auto set a field of a model to the user that is submitting the form.

Models.py:

```
class startcampaign(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   description = models.TextField()
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Forms.py:

```
class StartCampaignsForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = startcampaign
    exclude =['user']
```

Views.py:

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = StartCampaignsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        campaign_register = StartCampaignsForm.save(commit=False)
        campaign_register.user = self.objects.get(user=self.user)
        campaign_register.save(commit=True)
        return redirect('home')
else:
    form = StartCampaignsForm()
return render(request, 'Campaigns/register.html', {'form': form})
```

When I run this currently, I get save() is missing a positional argument 'self'.
I' not dedicated to this method. I just need a working example that lets me autoset the user which is submitting the form to the foreign key field of 'user' in my model.

Answer (score 1):

Your user should be logged in for this to work.

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = StartCampaignsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        campaign_register = StartCampaignsForm.save(commit=False)
        campaign_register.user = request.user
        campaign_register.save(commit=True)
        return redirect('home')
else:
    form = StartCampaignsForm()
return render(request, 'Campaigns/register.html', {'form': form})
```